# "The title of Bachelor of Engineering" vs "the title Bachelor of Engineering"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, definite-articles, honorifics

> 1. ... obtained the diploma and the title of Bachelor of Engineering (B.Eng.).
> 2. ... obtained the diploma and the title Bachelor of Engineering (B.Eng).

Which sentence is correct? Which is better?

Comment: ... obtained a BEng.

Comment: If you must pad it out, "diploma and title" actually has a single word, *degree*. But "... obtained a Bachelor of Engineering degree" without *of* at all.

Comment: I have to use 'diploma and title'.

Comment: It's not English. English uses the single word *degree*. See [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/degree) sense 5 and 6.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well, it's clearly *English.* "Title and degree" may not be idiomatic in your experience, but that's not to say it's not an understandable and grammatically correct phrase constructed in the English language.

Comment: I would take 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that "Bachelor of Engineering" isn't a "title" in an idiomatic English sense, at least in American English (UK/Aussie commenters, feel free to disagree). As a native speaker, I would be more likely to say:

In 1995, I graduated with a bachelor's degree in Engineering (B. Eng.) from the University of...

or

In 1995, I obtained a bachelor's degree in Engineering (B. Eng.) from the University of...

or

In 1995, I received a bachelor's degree in Engineering (B. Eng.) from the University of...

or

In 1995, I graduated from the University of Stackchangistan with a bachelor's degree in Engineering (B. Eng.)

In English (at least in American English), if you talk about receiving a diploma rather than a degree, it sounds a bit like you're talking about the graduation ceremony. But at a pinch, you could say you received a B. Eng. diploma. You should probably not say that you received a "title" from an academic institution; it is not idiomatic.

Answer (score -3):

"...obtained the diploma and Bachelor title in Engineering(B.Eng.)"

Just a suggestion.

Comment: I can't agree with this. It doesn't "sound right" and I'd consider it a worse suggestion than either of the two the OP posed.

Comment: As a native speaker of Mid-Atlantic American English, this does not sound correct to me at all.